# Xquartz on Mavericks 10.9 fails

Tags: macos, macports, x11, xquartz

There is an issue with running xquartz on my system.  I installed it by using the link from the Apple website. However when I run xquartz from terminal I get:

```
:~$ xquartz
/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11: line 10: /usr/local/bin/bash: No such file or directory
/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11: line 10: exec: /usr/local/bin/bash: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

This is preventing me from launching xquartz/x11 applications that I downloaded through macports.  How can I resolve this so that xquartz runs properly?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/bash` an executable/binary or a symlink to one?

Comment: I did not have any reference to bash in the folder.  I created a symlink for it and it resolved my errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app/Contents/MacOS/X11` is just a shell script that executes whatever is defined as `$SHELL` in your environment:

```
case $(basename "${SHELL}") in
    bash)          exec -l "${SHELL}" --login -c 'exec "${@}"' - "${@}" ;;
```

(etc).

In your case, it look as though `$SHELL` is set to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, which doesn't exist. What's interesting, though, is that since you have a prompt at which you have typed `xquartz`, you clearly are running a shell of some description. However, it doesn't correspond to the value of `$SHELL`.

Two suggestions for how this might happen:

1. `$SHELL` will normally reflect the login shell for your user. You can set that in System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> right click on your username and choose "Advanced Options". If you set this to an invalid value, you won't normally be able to open a terminal... unless you go into the Terminal.app preferences and set the "Shells open with:" option to something which does exist. You'll then get a working terminal with a non-existent `$SHELL`.
2. Alternatively, it might be something in your shell startup scripts (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc) which export a misleading value of `$SHELL` to the environment. If you have customized any of these, take a look and make sure you're not setting things up incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for your help; it helped me understand the problem and implement a fix. You're right, I had a shell open already and used `which bash` to give me the correct path. I then created a symlink to that bash and put it in `/usr/local/bin/bash`.  I am now able to use xquartz, tested with xclock, gimp, etc.